# Should my mechs have an artillery gun installed onto their back?

Tags: technology, science-fiction, warfare, military, mechs

I’ve decided to add mechs into my world to act as a force multiplication unit as well as an anti-[zombie] horde asset. Yes, I know that mechs are unrealistic and impractical at best but I just want to add a cool-factor into my world.

Anyway, the mechs (known as the **Mechanized Combat Platform**/MCP) in my world are about 15 meters in height and have enough room to fit in six people (the Unit Commander, Gunner, Assistant Gunner, two Mechanics, and Pilot). The Mechanized Combat Platforms have the following as their (current) armament:

- Some type of heavy gun that can cause serious damage to tanks and other armored vehicles as well as enemy infantry in a direct-fire role (still searching)
- Two M242 Bushmaster autocannons
- GAU-12 Equalizer rotary autocannon
- Two Mk 19 automatic grenade launchers
- Two twin-barrel M2 Browning Machine Guns (for crew use against hostile combatants and zombies)

I’ve thought about about including some type artillery gun and putting it on the MCP’s back kind of like what Pacific Rim did with [Coyote Tango](https://images.app.goo.gl/sryYtYkyZKktvQkV8) (except with just one howitzer instead of two). I was thinking of using either the [M777 howitzer](https://images.app.goo.gl/rpHjshJm7MH3pNVh9)  or [M119 howitzer](https://images.app.goo.gl/QMa5Ef7um7sV5H269) as the “backpack howitzer” but I’ve also thought about using a mortar instead. Regardless of what I choose, the howitzer or mortar will operate on a sliding rail system where the gun can move up and down the MCP’s back to provide either indirect or direct fire support.

But in general, would it be a good idea to include an artillery gun onto the back of the MCP? How effective would this be?

Comment: This seems pretty opinion based. Kind of either yes or no. Or perhaps maybe. Generally I don't mind opinion based queries when there's good worldbuilding basis to the question. But this is ***literally*** just "yeah go for it" or "no, don't do that"!

Comment: Zombies? The fact that it's 50ft tall and has giant metal feet should be all you need. Stomp stomp. Artillery is overkill. Guns don't need to be big to slag tanks, little tiny anti-tank weapons in tubes a man can put on his shoulder often do the job. Unless you want a cool factor, obviously.

Comment: Are you seriously asking how effective would be the secondary armament of an utterly **in**effective weapons platform? The only question you should be asking *yourself* is whether the vertically mobile cannon would be effective *for the plot*.

Comment: This might do better if re-worded and made into a [tag:reality-check] question. Changing "should I add a weapon" to *"given the following specifications and enemy types (variety, potential threat to mech, and amount expected to face): would an artillery gun like `<add example here>` be feasible?"*

Comment: Note for the above to work - it would need substantial information on the logistics, enemy makeup, and environment that one expects to face or it will be near impossible to answer with a solid answer (i.e. something other than *"it depends on ...."* which is what this is currently at)

Comment: @user535733 I’m talking specifically about a howitzer or mortar in the back of the mech. The other weapons I listed are just to give an idea of the current armament of my mechs.

Comment: Howitzer vs. mortar depends upon the range you want and your likely targets. Will multiple mechs be massing fires against an armored formation 15km away? That's a howitzer job. Will a single mech be firing to break up a knot of missileers in the open 3km away? That's a mortar task. Whether or not either is a good idea is really up to you. (yeah go for it!) Guns and ammo are heavy -- they might slow your mech down, or reduce effectiveness in some terrain. And they need to stand still for a moment, well-braced, when they fire a howitzer.

Comment: You have a mech but you are using guns that are over 100 years old?  I hope your scenario is set in 1980.  On my mech I will have 3 railguns and different ammo types.  Tungsten for the tanks.  Steel flechettes for the zombies.

Answer (score 3):

This will be a weird way to answer a question, but hopefully it will be helpful.

I used to play a lot of the paper and dice version of Starfleet Battles and one of my favorite ships was a light battleship that I had custom modified such that 90% of its weapons pointed aft.  I referred to it as a Federation Science Vessel before and during play so that my opponents weren't surprised when its forward facing weapons appeared underrated.  They would attack and after a feeble frontal attack, I would turn and run from the fight.  Eager for the kill, my enemies would start to chase and because I had also upgraded the engines, they would quickly fall into formation directly behind me... right in the center of my weapons' scope.  Then all I had to do was let them catch up enough that they were in my optimum weapons range before barraging them brutally.  And the best part is they had to sit there in my line of fire getting slammed.  They couldn't swerve or evade without giving up the pursuit, so either they gave up or died in my wake.  It was an amazingly effective strategy, but usually got me criticized for behavior not worthy of a starfleet officer.  So the next time I would play against those particular players, I would introduce them to my Romulan "science vessel".

Rear mounted weapons are great because they let you control the vector of combat while simultaneously running for your life.

Comment: +1 just for the excellent use of SFB nostalgia.

Answer (score 1):

Choice of weapon is highly functional depending on the planned role of the platform i.e. what you are going to be shooting at. Hence a tank has a main gun and a machine-gun or two for close-quarters, an SPG has a single largest-possible cannon, and MRL has a load of rocket launch tubes.

Pretty much nothing has the sort of weird mix 'n' match assortment you're proposing, for the obvious reason that it's not very practical :).  Since you're committed to looking cool, I'd go with that and forget about practical considerations.

FWIW guns are increasingly outmoded, guided missiles or drones would be more the thing for anything set in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The one reason we don't have such military mechs on our world is because tanks are more effective for the role. A pair of sliding guns supported in such a way is much closer to how a tank works than guns being held on arms, or swiveling as arms as we see in so much mech literature. Therefore your mechs would be less ineffective in combat.

Besides, if it works for the Singeki no Kyojin's Cart Titan, it should work for mechs.

[image: Cart Titan with a huge gun on her back]
[image: Cart Titan with some gun stations on her back]